# Pattern for Returning *all* the reasons something is invalid

Tags: design-patterns

Is there a pattern that helps tell the user at runtime *all* the reasons their object (or payload) is invalid?

I have an object Foo that, to be valid, needs params **a** and **b** to not be null. Unfortunately the parent method that creates it does not guarantee those params will not be null.

I can solve for this with something like the below, but it feels messy and like it won't scale nicely. Is there a better pattern for this?

```
fun parentMethod(a: String?, b: String?){
  // do stuff
  try {
    val foo = Foo(a, b)
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    LOG.info("Exception when creating a Foo", e.message) // contain *all* error messages
  }
}

class Foo(a: String?, b: String?){
  init {
    val errors = []
    if(a == null){ // How do I tame this?
      errors.push("a cannot be null)
    }
    if(b == null){
      errors.push("b cannot be null")
    }
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      throw InvalidFooException(errors.toString())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My first thought was a Builder Pattern. You can check your constraints in the `build` method and I think it won't feel messy anymore. I assume that this is pseudo code, because a builder pattern better plays out its strengths with more complex object creations.

Comment: This is probably going to be language specific. I suggest tagging the question with the language you are programming in.

Answer (score 0):

With your code example you are expressing the "Factory Method" pattern, with only small change to make: `parentMethod` should be static inside `Foo` class, which itself should make its constructor private. This way, `parentMethod` alone will be able to construct `Foo`.

Now, `parentMethod` can safely be responsible for checking `a` and `b`.

It is possible to take it further and implement a classic validation pattern, leaving factory to focus on construction only, here's a pseudo:

```
interface IValidator {
  validate(x: String?): bool
}

class EmptyValidator : IValidator {
  validate(x: String?): bool {
    return (x == null or x == "")
  }
}

fun fooFactory(a: String?, b: String?, validators: IValidator[]) {
  // Loop through validators array and throw error
  // when any validator returns false; if no error thrown, construct Foo;
  // or, accumulate falsy validations without throwing errors until all 
  // validations done
}
```